# The best way to resize windows in macOs app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have this code to get all the information about all apps opened in my mac.
The way to get this information is when the cursor is over the app.

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var mouseLocation: NSPoint = .zero
    @Published var openWindows: [NSWindowInfo] = []

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Register for global mouse move events
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) { event in
            self.handleGlobalMouseMove(event)
        }

        // Get all open windows on launch
        self.updateOpenWindows()
    }

    private func handleGlobalMouseMove(_ event: NSEvent) {
        // Handle mouse move event here
        // You can update the mouseLocation in your ContentView or take other actions.
        self.mouseLocation = event.locationInWindow

        // Get all windows currently on the screen
        self.updateOpenWindows()

        // Highlight the window under the mouse cursor
        let windowNumber = CGWindowID(event.windowNumber)
        if let windowInfo = openWindows.first(where: { $0.windowNumber == windowNumber }) {
            print(windowInfo.title)
            print(windowNumber)
        }
    }

    private func updateOpenWindows() {
        var windows: [NSWindowInfo] = []

        let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
        let cgWindowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID)
        if let cfArrayRef = cgWindowListInfo {
            let cfArray = unsafeBitCast(cfArrayRef, to: NSArray.self)
            for window in cfArray {
                if let dict = window as? NSDictionary,
                   let windowNumber = dict[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? CGWindowID,
                   let boundsDict = dict[kCGWindowBounds as String] as? NSDictionary,
                   let title = dict[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as? String,
                   let bounds = CGRect(dictionaryRepresentation: boundsDict) {
                    windows.append(NSWindowInfo(title: title, bounds: bounds, windowNumber: Int(windowNumber)))

                    // Get the corresponding NSWindow instance
                    if let windowInstance = NSApp.window(withWindowNumber: Int(windowNumber)) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        openWindows = windows
    }
```

When move the courser over the windows I print into the console two vales title and windowsNumber

when I clicked any app I need to resize the windows to full screen. What is the best way to do that.

Comment: If you want to resize the windows, you'll have to use Accessibility APIs.

Comment: Or AppleScript with SystemEvents, which uses accessibility as well.